# how to pass the NSMutableArray to UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, core-data

data values i have one text filed and two buttons.One button is save,second button is show. 
when click save button data will be Stored in Core-Data and then i click Show button data will be displayed on Console. It gone nice.
But now i want when Click show button data will be displayed on UITableView So Please Give me any idea 
Thanks in advanced,
this is my code:-

```
#import "SetViewController.h"
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@interface SetViewController ()
{

    NSMutableArray *array;
}
@end

@implementation SetViewController
@synthesize textField;
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)save:(id)sender {
    AppDelegate *appD=(AppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
    NSEntityDescription *entit=[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Team" inManagedObjectContext:appD.managedObjectContext];

    [entit setValue:textField.text forKey:@"fname"];
    NSError *error;
    BOOL isSaved=[appD.managedObjectContext save:&error];
    NSLog(@"succesfully saved flag: %d",isSaved);

}

- (IBAction)show:(id)sender {

    AppDelegate *appDelegat=(AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];

    NSEntityDescription *entity=[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Team" inManagedObjectContext:appDelegat.managedObjectContext];

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRr = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]init];
    [fetchRr setEntity:entity];


    array=[[appDelegat.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRr error:nil]mutableCopy];
    NSLog(@"array %@",array);


    for (NSManagedObject *obj in array) {
        NSLog(@"Name :%@\n",[obj valueForKey:@"fname"]);

    }

}

-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{

    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}

@end

i am tried like this :-
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"ShowData"])
    {

        ShowViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
        destViewController.second = [[array valueForKey:@"fname"] componentsJoinedByString(angry)" , "];
        NSLog(@" got data for array %@",destViewController.second);
    }
}
```

ShowViewController.h:-

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "SetViewController.h"

@interface ShowViewController : UITableViewController<UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource>
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *second;
@end
```

ShowViewController.m:-

```
import "ShowViewController.h"

@interface ShowViewController ()
{
    NSMutableArray *acess;
}
@end

@implementation ShowViewController
@synthesize second;
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];



    acess =[second componentsSeparatedByString:@", "];


}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [acess count];
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (!cell)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] ;
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = [acess objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;

}
```

ShowViewController is UITableView.When Click UItableView is open but data will be not Displayed So Please give me any idea

Comment: it's much easier to understand if you use dots between sentences

Comment: Have you studied the tableview programming guide or searched for tableview tutorials - there are plenty around.  You need to implement the table view delegate and dataSource protocols

Comment: @Paulw11 thanks for replay  now i add code please check and then give me any idea about my problem

Comment: What is the type of the property second?  What is your cellForRowAtIndexPath method in ShowViewController ?

Comment: @Paulw11 please look my code once now add ShowViewController and then Give me any Idea

Answer (score 1):

Follow following steps and also read programming guide of UITableview provided by apple:

1. After getting the array just reload your table view.
2. Make number of rows = array count.
3. Customize the cell as per your need.

Answer (score 0):

If you only declared the array as per you shown in code then you must need to initialise it in view did load like this:

```
array=[NSMutablearray array];
```

after that get the values from db and stored in array an use UITable view delegate and datasource methods.

Answer (score 0):

First declare your array in your viewDidload() method.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
yourArray=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:Obj1,obj2,obj3,obj4,obj5, nil];
}
```

and then use tableview delegate methods. to set array data to tableview.

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{

    // Return the number of sections.
     return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

     // Return the number of rows in the section.
     return [yourArray count];
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
      UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

       // Configure the cell...

   if (cell == nil)
    {
       cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
     }

       cell.textLabel.text=[yourArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
       return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you already have an `NSArray` that contains your strings, there is no need to go through the whole componentsJoinedByString/componentsSeparatedByString - you can just pass the array to your second view controller.

Accessing the passed data in `viewDidLoad` won't work though because when you set the property in `prepareForSegue` the view has already loaded.

Your `prepareForSegue` should be -

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"ShowData"])
    {

        ShowViewController *destViewController = (ShowViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
        destViewController.fnames = [array valueForKey:@"fname"];

    }
}
```

In your .h file for `ShowViewController` declare a property to receive frames -

```
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSArray *fnames;
```

Then your table data source methods will be -

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [self.fnames count];
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] ;
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = [self.fnames objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;

}
```

Comment: i am run as you said but it's still showing empty tableView SO please give me any idea

Comment: You need to use the debugger and step through your code - are the variables set to what they should be or are they nil?

Comment: Also, make sure your table methods are being called - have you assigned the data source and delegate properties to your view controller class?

Comment: when print destViewController.fnames it's showing null value

Comment: So, you need to work out why.  Set a breakpoint in prepreForSegue. Is valueForKey returning a valid array?